# Render view blank

Tags: rendering

[Blender Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ww831fve76pas1ah0taqt/Straw.blend?rlkey=30i25dbxlb28sqfgf8g6jujx2&dl=0)

Ok, I've searched hours of youtube and google and all the fixes are not working.

- The compositor node is connected to the output
- The No objects are hidden or disabled for rendering
- The lights are active
- Have no surface and environment filters
- Clip is in the camera view
- There's only one camera and it's facing and covering the object
- Have no timeline, just trying to render a 3d object as is.

Tried both cycles and evee, high quality normals selected, I've clicked literally every option in the view and render and nothing makes it show.
Render region on or off, doesn't do anything.

Tried Ctrl B to do render area and didn't do anything.
Hit W to select or deselect everything and no effect.

Tried blasting lights to maximum all around the object, no effect.

Only thing I've found online was the Filter option to check environment and surfaces does not exist in version 3.6.  So I can't find those to check them and see if it works.
Post Processing options didn't change anything either.

I can't find anything else why I can't see render.

All I did was start from scratch, delete the original cube, add a cylinder, created a straw, moved camera to show the straw, which isn't doing anything, and render shows blank screen.

Then go through every single troubleshooting step and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

select your (hidden) camera (not camera.001) and then change the clip end to 1000:

[image]

Comment: Just did and it didn't work.  I even deleted it and had the new camera and didn't work.  I must have ctrl Z more than I thought and brought it back when I had it saved.

I'm actually really confused on this, because when I tried copy and pasting it into another project to test.....I noticed it was not showing render either, and then when I just now reloaded the other project that I literally JUST exported yesterday before this issue....it now no longer shows me the render either.

I went into settings and can't find anything that was changed from before, I never went in after export though

Comment: i just can say, i downloaded your file, i did that, and it rendered. So i can only assume you have another problem.

Comment: Yeah after seeing my other project not showing anymore also.....I don't know what it could be.  I checked the preferences and can't find anything in there that would have changed to no longer show renders.....